# Problem to access site

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am trying to access a site with Tor, I get the following message:
`Secure Connection Failed An error occurred during a connection to www.xxxx.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR`, I added the `Select a built-in bridge` then chose `obfs4`, without this option chosen I neither can access the site with Tor. So it's clear the site is blocking Tor but It still can detect Tor when `obfs4` is selected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Obsf4](https://support.torproject.org/glossary/obfs4/) is a type of pluggable transport used with a bridge (unlisted Tor guard node) to let Tor users access the internet in countries which censor the Tor network. It does nothing against stopping websites from blocking Tor users.

If the website is blocking Tor users, then it might not be possible to visit the site. Only the website owner has control on whether Tor users can visit the site or not. The best option is to contact the site directly and kindly ask them to unblock Tor users. However, they may not do this because some of Tor traffic can be bots, attackers, spammers, etc. and may threaten the security of the website.